# On emitting signal, control comes back to the same class in qt

Tags: qt, signals-slots

In my application I am deleting a label and in method I emit a signal after deleting label and in other class I used a slot to connect to that signal. After that in that slot I don't want to return to previous class. how can I do that?

Comment: What you mean by "return to a class"?

Comment: Show code. Explain what you want to achieve. What is your root problem?

Comment: where would you like control to go instead?!

Answer (score 1):

As i know, the default connection of Qt's signal is autoconnection, which actually is directconnection in single Thread.

I guess you are in single Thread app.

When a signal is emitting, it is actually calling slot method, just like general function call.

For a example:

```
void test()
{
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    test();
}
```

So it will return to your calling method.

There are some standard way to use Qt. You don't need to play tricks.